# Possible to split virtual host definitions into multiple apache conf files?

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have a single server that I use to host a whole bunch of smallish websites. It's recently come to my attention that a service called LetsEncrypt allows me to get an SSL certificate for free. The catch, as far as I can tell, is that they don't allow you to do any traditional SSL setup and instead you must use a script they provide which automatically requests a certificate for your server and configures apache for it. The problem, now, is that their setup script does not support the fact that I have 8+ virtual hosts all in my single 000-default.conf file for apache.

So my question is, how do I configure apache to read multiple site configuration files so that I can separate my different virtual host definitions into different files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Include` directive to include other config files and split up your main config.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

You can also use wildcards, so you can have each virtual host in a separate config file and include all without having to modify your main config file:

```
Include conf/extra/vhosts/*.conf
```

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include

Comment: I was going to say that, but you beat me to it. lol

Comment: I am a fan of the ole' sites-available with separate confs per site. You can still use a wildcard like in your example. This directory should already exist with a 000-default.conf in most installs. Either way, the same thing.

Comment: I used this approach for developing in macOs 10.14